# What is difference between retrieve data in android from .json , .xml extension?

Tags: php, android, json, xml

I know it's basis question. but 
Is there any difference between retrieve data from extensions end with `.xml`  and `.json` or it's depend on the **Response** only ?

Is there any difference in speed, quality, etc.. ?

I retrieved data with `xml`,`json` but i didn't know the difference,

I use json for big applications or xml ? or both ?

I'm searching for **Performance , Quality**

Comment: .php file will return JSON data. JSON is not file it is a data format.

Comment: I've answered the basic difference of these file extensions below, but please consider providing more information about you usecase. Where are you encountering these files while developing Android? Are you trying to consume data from an API?

Comment: Its the response that matters not the extension in link .

Comment: JSON and XML are formats. Therefore responses can be in these formats. PHP is a server side language and can return responses in any sort of format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JSON**

JSON is a data format. Response received in JSON format is in object or list of objects, so you can map object directly to your model using GSON

JSON sample:-

```
{ "name":"John" }
```

**XML**

XML is a Data format as well but retrieving data from this type is bit tricky because data is kept in property then parent then child

XML sample:-

```
<catalog_item gender="Men's">
    <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
    <price>39.95</price>
    <size description="Medium">
        <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
        <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
    </size>
    <size description="Large">
        <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
        <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
    </size>
</catalog_item>
```

**PHP**

This is a Server-side language JSON and XMLs can be sent through PHP

**Difference, Speed, Quality**

Talking about the difference here both are different datasets. So, talking about quality, JSON is far so easy to deal with and it is very well arranged to retrieve datasets from it, as compare to XML. XML have messy datasets and it takes time to parse responses from XML. As per quality concerns, JSON is better in sense of quality compare to XML due to its parsing and mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing different layers.

PHP is a programming language.
XML and JSON are standard data formats.
A PHP based webservice can return JSON or XML payloads. Since both are basically text, speed should be similar. You can experiment differences based on how big the payload is (JSON format is less verbose than XML), how complex is and how are you processing it.

Another possibility is that you are attempting to read a PHP webpage. In that case, again, you are not reading PHP. You are reading HTML, CSS, etc.  That's called web scraping. That's slower than reading a standard data format for obvious reasons: You have to format the data in the webpage in order to send it for display.

Ideally, you should never rely on web scraping directly on the device. It's slower, and any changes in the webpage will break the app. In that case, perform the scrap in a server and send a standard payload to the app.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a data format. The name stands for Javascript Object Notation. It is commonly used for transmitting data between clients and APIs, so this is absolutely a format you may come across in Android when retrieving data from a remote server.

[PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php) is a programming language, primarily used for web development. It can print anything out to the client, so the output could be in HTML (a webpage to be viewed in the browser), JSON (see above, commonly for an API), or many other forms. When you say that you have retrieved a PHP file, you probably mean a URL ending in `.php`. Somewhat confusingly, the content returned from such a URL isn't actually in PHP, but is being generated by PHP. You could retrieve data from an API in JSON format, but if it was generated by a PHP script, it may come from a URL containing the `.php` file extension.

So to answer your question, you Android app might read JSON data from a source (or even store data as JSON in some cases), but it will never directly deal with PHP code – it may just be the consumer of something generated by PHP.

Comment: The file extension doesn't always inherently tell you what is in the file (sadly). A `.json` file will almost always be JSON data, however as I noted in the PHP section of my answer, a `.php` extension on the internet could be returning just about anything to you, with HTML being the most common and JSON probably being in the top two to five.

Answer (score 0):

Php is a scripting language and JSON/XML is just a response in this reference.

Php or any other language may returns responses like json/xml.

So you have to first understand what is server responses and how to generate json/xml response from php or any other language.

Here are some references:

[link1](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp)

[link2](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-json-parsing-retrieve-from-mysql-database/)